# How to get traverse DOM path from one element to another (using Firebug)?

Tags: dom, firebug, dom-traversal

I have e.g. this structure:

```
<div id="items">
  <div class="item">
    <span class="date">5 Feb 2016</span>
    <span class="title">
      <a href="http://example.com">Title 1</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the full traverse path from `#items` to `a` - in my case it is:

```
firstChild.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild
```

or

```
childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[0]
```

When I write in Firebug's command line:

```
document.getElementById('items');
```

I can see the element and can right-click it and choose *Inspect in DOM Panel* to see it there. I can then find this path by expanding the properties `childNodes` or `firstChild` + `nextSibling`.

When I reach my element (`a` in my example) in *DOM* panel, I then right-click it and choose *Copy Path* from the menu to get the path mentioned above.

My question is, is there a solution to simplify these steps?

- Code in JavaScript
- Plugin for Firefox or Firebug
- Remove other properties (excluding `childNodes`, `attributes`, `nodeValue`, etc.) from the *DOM* panel
- Other solution (outside of Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Firebug has a function [`getPropertyPath()`](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/305f4912b6a476bfc2ab1b7c174d826892b1863a/extension/content/firebug/dom/domBasePanel.js#L449) to get the DOM path. What this function does is to up the DOM tree and add each item to an array, which is joined to a string at the end.

Comment: 1. I didn't found it.
2. As I understand result of this function the same, which I have by copy path. I know, how get copy, I need simplifying my actions.

Comment: Note that I linked the function above to the Firebug code. You should note in your question what you have tried so far.